# How to measure memory useage of a OpenMP code in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, openmp, intel-fortran

How can I measure memory usage of my OpenMP code? I believe, the memory usage will reduce with number of thread.

I am using Linux and the Intel Fortran compiler.

Comment: *"I believe, the memory usage will reduce with number of thread."*  Why do you think so? I don't. Certainly not in general.

Comment: You may be able to run `/usr/bin/time -l ./yourProgram`

Comment: I have learnt that from the following link http://www.nersc.gov/users/computational-systems/retired-systems/hopper/performance-and-optimization/using-openmp-effectively-on-hopper/

Comment: ..  then look for *"max resident set size"*

Comment: You are misunderstanding that link. It says that memory usage is smaller i**in comparison with other parallel approaches**. Not in comparison with no threading at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/usr/bin/time` with the `-l` parameter for that. So, you would run:

```
/usr/bin/time -l ./yourProgram
```

As I don't have your program, I will give an example with `dd` creating blocks of 1MB, 2MB, 4MB and 8MB and discarding them:

With a 1MB memory block:

```
/usr/bin/time -l dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1024k count=1
...
1855488  maximum resident set size
...
```

With a 2MB memory block:

```
/usr/bin/time -l dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=2048k count=1
...
2904064  maximum resident set size
...
```

With a 4MB memory block:

```
/usr/bin/time -l dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=4096k count=1
...
5001216  maximum resident set size
...
```

With an 8MB memory block:

```
/usr/bin/time -l dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=8192k count=1
...
9195520  maximum resident set size
...
```